# How to prevent message commit after caught the exception in client-acknowledge mode in camel

Tags: exception, apache-camel

Now I have a program to listen a jms queue, and it use client-acknowledge mode to commit transaction after the program consumed the message without exception.

```
public void process(Exchange exch) throws Exception {
        JmsMessage message = (JmsMessage) exch.getIn();
        try {
            ...
            javax.jms.Message msg = message.getJmsMessage();
            log.info("commit ems level transaction");
            msg.acknowledge();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            ...
        }
    }
```

```
<camelContext id="JMS_MCI" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
        <endpoint id="commonJmsMciInQue" uri="QUEUE">
            <property key="testConnectionOnStartup" value="true" />
            <property key="disableReplyTo" value="true" />
            <property key="concurrentConsumers" value="10" />
            <property key="acknowledgementModeName" value="CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE" />
        </endpoint>
</camelContext>
```

And I try to set breakpoint on my program, when it caught exception, in case the exception handling code has not finished executing, the message is still exist in the queue, once the exception handling code has finished executing, the message is deleted.

So how to stop the message commit when it caught the ecxeption?

Thanks for you help!~~

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using Camel, why do you "get your hands dirty" by programming against the [JMS API](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/package-summary.html)? Camels [JMS component](http://camel.apache.org/jms.html) does all this for you for free.

Just use [local JMS transactions](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_fuse/6.2/html/transaction_guide/fmrtxnjms) (without external transaction manager) for message consumption and Camel automatically commits successfully processed messages and rolls back messages with processing errors (message broker then does a redelivery or moves the message to a [DLQ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_letter_queue)).

The key for this setup is to configure the Camel JMS component correctly. For [ActiveMQ](http://camel.apache.org/activemq.html) you can do it like this

```
@Bean("activemq")
public ActiveMQComponent createActiveMQComponent(final ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    final ActiveMQComponent activeMQComponent = new ActiveMQComponent();
    final JmsConfiguration jmsConfiguration = new JmsConfiguration();
    jmsConfiguration.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    jmsConfiguration.setLazyCreateTransactionManager(false);
    jmsConfiguration.setTransacted(true);
    jmsConfiguration.setConcurrentConsumers([number of concurrent consumers]);
    jmsConfiguration.setCacheLevelName("CACHE_CONSUMER");
    activeMQComponent.setConfiguration(jmsConfiguration);
    return activeMQComponent;
}
```

The important part of this are these two configurations.

```
jmsConfiguration.setLazyCreateTransactionManager(false);
jmsConfiguration.setTransacted(true);
```

This component configuration combined with **NO** Spring transaction manager configured, gives you local transactions with your broker.

If this setup is done, you can just write your routes to consume messages from queues:

```
from("activemq:queue:myQueue")
...
```

You **must not** use the Camel `transacted()` statement in your routes because this is related to a configured transaction manager and not applicable for local JMS transactions. But don't worry, if the setup above is correct, your JMS consumer routes are perfectly transacted without `transacted()`.

You also don't need to configure your queues as in your example. You can configure queue endpoints in Camel as simple strings as in my example

```
from("activemq:queue:myQueue")
activemq = component name
queue = consume from a queue (not a topic)
myQueue = queue name
```

If you want to, you can also handle processing errors with [Camel error handler](http://camel.apache.org/error-handler.html). But be sure to understand the difference between Broker redelivery (Message is sent again) and Camel redelivery (only processing step is repeated).

Comment: It use default `acknowledgementModeName` before, and now i must use client mode to control when to commit transaction, and `camel.message` has no method for me, so i used `jms.message` to acknowledge. And I found that even I set client-mode, it always commit transaction whatever the program throw exception or it run well, even I didn't call message.acknowledge method

Comment: When you consume transacted (that is not auto-ack nor client-ack), successful messages are commited and failed messages are not commited. Is this what you are looking for or do you have to do more than that?

Comment: Once I got the message from queue, I would analyze it and persist it into DB. Now I suppose the db is down and I have got the message, it would thrown the sql exception and the message was  deleted from the queue. Now what I want is that before the message persist into db, the message cannot be deleted from the queue

Comment: That sounds exactly what a Camel transactional JMS consumer does for you

Comment: Any website or example? Thanks a lot

Comment: Now I use `SESSION_TRANSACTED` instead of `CLIENT-ACK`, and use `session.commit()` and `session.rollback()` to control, but I found that when I use `rollback`, my program would always consume this message although the message always exist in queue. So any way to avoid my program always consume the message once it `rollback`, or if I start two program nodes, does it useful?

Comment: I extended my answer with examples. you probably also find complete examples online if you search for Camel JMS consumer examples or something similar